# What is the most efficient way to import a plain-text table as a data cube where the slices are determined by where the value of one column changes?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a data file containing the evolution of a spectrum over time. I can load the data with `np.loadtxt`, but this returns a 2D array with 3 columns - an accurate representation of the file, but not the best structure for looping over each time interval. I would like to reshape the data into a cube where each slice contains the spectrum at a single timestep.

The input file looks like this:

```
Time    Wavelength    Flux
1.0     100           30
1.0     101           29
1.0     102           31
...
1.0     200           43
2.0     100           30
2.0     101           29.5
...
2.0     200           42
3.0     100           31
3.0     101           32
...
100     200           37
```

`np.loadtxt` returns an n x 3 array, where n is the number of rows in the file. I would like my code shape the data into a cube using the rows where the time column increments as break points. In other words, I would like to have a list of spectra, where each spectrum is one timestep later than the previous one. [Here's a visual reperesentation of what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohdWP.png)

I can think of a number of ways to manually loop over the data and force it into a usable format, but that seems both unpythonic and computationally inefficient. I will be using this code a lot, on many different files, so I can't hard code in the number of rows in a single slice. I looked at `np.shape`, but it doesn't seem to have an obvious faster way to accomplish this.

Is there a faster, more pythonic way to accomplish this? Or is the only workable way to loop over the file every time to manually determine the break points?

Comment: If the number of rows per timestep is constant in a given file and you can easily figure out the number of timesteps in the file, then you should be able to use that in `numpy.reshape` to get the shape you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think that your question could have some extra informations as, the number of rows with different time steps are always the same in this data? and in the other files, they will be the same as well?

Regardless, as for sure you know how many you have, you could use `numpy.split` in your array, to separate your array in blocks of same time.

In a more brute force, but maybe better, if the quantity of rows with same time varies , you could separate those using a `for` loop and `numpy.append` to create sub arrays with the same time.

**Edit**

From what you gave, you basically need to know how many rows from the time steps you have from each file.

As I don't have your data, I build an artificial_data to exemplify

```
import numpy as np

length=np.random.randint(6,9)

artificial_data = np.transpose((np.concatenate((np.ones(length),2*np.ones(length),3*np.ones(length),4*np.ones(length))),
              np.concatenate((np.random.rand(length),np.random.rand(length),np.random.rand(length),np.random.rand(length))),
              np.concatenate((np.random.rand(length),np.random.rand(length),np.random.rand(length),np.random.rand(length)))))

artificial_data
```

which gives (those are random numbers, so it will change every time you run )

```
array([[1.        , 0.62337349, 0.84582971],
       [1.        , 0.38484415, 0.57365805],
       [1.        , 0.80504472, 0.67706586],
       [1.        , 0.49799682, 0.69909408],
       [1.        , 0.06563674, 0.51799158],
       [1.        , 0.65680522, 0.7616487 ],
       [1.        , 0.11497811, 0.67833476],
       [2.        , 0.74605054, 0.40117761],
       [2.        , 0.47544047, 0.40270957],
       [2.        , 0.79241801, 0.92569317],
       [2.        , 0.69839158, 0.21629401],
       [2.        , 0.7169591 , 0.32631124],
       [2.        , 0.8832162 , 0.55114389],
       [2.        , 0.91455405, 0.28574292],
       [3.        , 0.61089879, 0.77563826],
       [3.        , 0.15776237, 0.64906268],
       [3.        , 0.80971068, 0.76695185],
       [3.        , 0.88994052, 0.07681381],
       [3.        , 0.71479789, 0.50768739],
       [3.        , 0.56042634, 0.25032607],
       [3.        , 0.44866057, 0.54832829],
       [4.        , 0.2643985 , 0.62251815],
       [4.        , 0.21353805, 0.91354626],
       [4.        , 0.75809504, 0.71601593],
       [4.        , 0.84296248, 0.87818252],
       [4.        , 0.95029666, 0.10553645],
       [4.        , 0.42500662, 0.92322183],
       [4.        , 0.95176257, 0.63409806]])
```

Now from the first column we can determine the maximum time step (I don't know if this quantity vary in your case).

With this number, basically we know how to split the data, so we transpose the data, drop the first column that has the time steps, we transpose it back to the original form and then we split according to the number of times. This looks like

```
num_of_time_steps = int(max(np.transpose(artificial_data)[0]))
separated_data = np.split(np.transpose(np.transpose(artificial_data)[1:]),num_of_time_steps)
separated_data
```

which gives the desired output

```
[array([[0.62337349, 0.84582971],
        [0.38484415, 0.57365805],
        [0.80504472, 0.67706586],
        [0.49799682, 0.69909408],
        [0.06563674, 0.51799158],
        [0.65680522, 0.7616487 ],
        [0.11497811, 0.67833476]]),
 array([[0.74605054, 0.40117761],
        [0.47544047, 0.40270957],
        [0.79241801, 0.92569317],
        [0.69839158, 0.21629401],
        [0.7169591 , 0.32631124],
        [0.8832162 , 0.55114389],
        [0.91455405, 0.28574292]]),
 array([[0.61089879, 0.77563826],
        [0.15776237, 0.64906268],
        [0.80971068, 0.76695185],
        [0.88994052, 0.07681381],
        [0.71479789, 0.50768739],
        [0.56042634, 0.25032607],
        [0.44866057, 0.54832829]]),
 array([[0.2643985 , 0.62251815],
        [0.21353805, 0.91354626],
        [0.75809504, 0.71601593],
        [0.84296248, 0.87818252],
        [0.95029666, 0.10553645],
        [0.42500662, 0.92322183],
        [0.95176257, 0.63409806]])]
```

Now you can acess each data from a given time step by the first index of separated data as

```
data_with_time_step_i = separated_data[i]
```

Hope that this helps you out, I couldn't elaborate something simpler than that

Comment: The number of rows per timestep should be consistent within each file, but I will be running this code on many different files, each of which could have a different number of rows per timestep.